# Get the Bootstrap pill to work inside a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a Bootstrap pills inside dropdown list inside a table table row. So, when an user selects the pill, then the right hand columns of that row get updated.

But the problem right now is that only one column gets updated in the row. And I also want the dropdown heading to show the selected item name in the list.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>SOR</th>
      <th>KPI</th>
      <th>Oty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Month</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">



        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           A
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">A</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">B</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">C</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">D</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



      </th>



      <td>
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">A</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">B</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">C</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">D</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">A</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">B</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">C</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">D</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">A</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">B</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">C</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">D</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/chris13786/r4Lv8uzz/

Comment: You have duplicated IDs in markup. Fix it, and then it could maybe work....

Comment: @sinisake but then how can I target more than one id's with one pill href?

Comment: huh, not sure, didn't used it, but you should use classes...

Answer (score 0):

You were not adding the HTML correctly see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/r4Lv8uzz/4/) or demo below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>SOR</th>
      <th>KPI</th>
      <th>Oty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Month</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            A
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">A</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">B</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">C</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">D</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



      </th>



      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            A
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab3" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab3" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">A</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab3" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">B</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab3" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">C</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab3" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">D</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            A
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">A</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">B</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">C</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">D</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            A
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">A</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">B</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">C</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">D</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```